# Geolocation in a background process

Tags: android, geolocation, alarmmanager, maui

I can't go into details why, but I am working on a Maui app for Android/iOS that needs to log geolocation information to a web API. That turned out to be quite easy. That's not the issue. The issue is that it needs to run even without the user interface open. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOakQq4GLU4 was a big help. However, while it worked in the emulator, it didn't work when it got on my real Android phone. I could swipe away the interface on the emulator and it kept running, but on the real thing, the process simply stopped. Also, the foreground operation produces an icon in the notification shader. This was not acceptable, either.

So, then I discovered WorkManager. After some fits and starts, I got that working. I was also happy that it could easily survive reboots and keep working. Only during testing did I discover far too late that the minimum timeout was 15 minutes. This wasn't acceptable. It had to be as often as once a minute.

Then I gave the AlarmManager a go. And I'm about to put my head through a wall. It seems to do what I want as often as I want. However, when I made this call:

```
location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);
```

The application just seized up. No exception, no return value. The Android complained that the app had stopped responding. To my mind, there some kind of threading difference between the calls from WorkManager and AlarmManager, but I haven't got a clue how to fix this.

I have a method in a class derived from Service:

```
    private void ScheduleAlarm(int minutes)
    {
        long intervalMillis = minutes * 60 * 1000; // Convert minutes to milliseconds
        long triggerTime = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + intervalMillis;
        _alarmManager?.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, triggerTime, intervalMillis, _pendingIntent);
    }
```

It works and the alarm triggers just fine, but the Geolocation call fails. And, as I said, the process works just fine if I'm calling it from a button on the user interface. And it worked in WorkManager... just the interval wasn't acceptable. But if called from AlarmManager, the app freezes.

Any advice appreciated. In fact, I'm up for anything other than the approaches I've tried.

Comment: Have you read this [Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)